# What processes are used by DRM?

Tags: osx, ps, drm

Whenever some content is DRM-protected, screenshots of such content are masked. Even using Terminal does not avoid such problems.

Which processes in `ps ax` are used by DRM that is implemented by iTunes?

Comment: Depends very much on how the DRM is implemented.

Comment: @andy Maybe you want to specify what DRM system it is, or at least what kind of contents?

Comment: @GuidoDomenici Is DRM not unique? It's iTunes that I meant in specific.

Comment: There are many DRM systems and iTunes is just one of them. I don't have a proper answer to your question (hence I'm putting this in a comment) but what I _can_ say is that typically these things are implemented at OS level. So the app would call an OS X API to the tune of "this surface is protected" and the OS will make sure to disable the other system APIs it normally enables for screenshots. There are similar APIs on Windows and on [Android](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9822607/71791).

Comment: @Andy iTunes AFAIK only runs on Mac and Windows... Could you clarify why you're asking this on Unix & Linux?

Comment: @derobert well, I use the terminal where I can see the processes Unix-like... where would this question fit the best?

Comment: @Andy which operating system are you running on? If Mac OS X, we take questions about the Unix underpinnings of it... but even if that's what you're asking about, it's still quite broad! You need to edit your question to at least limit to one DRM system. Also, if Mac OS X then possibly [apple.se] would be a better fit.

Comment: @derobert Done, I posted this there too: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/224363/what-processes-are-used-by-drm

Comment: @Andy you ignored the important bit about narrowing the scope of your question so it's answerable.

Comment: @derobert sorry, I didn't see that it's too broad.. now I hope the question is concrete